# Should I sell stocks after a buyout?

Tags: united-states, stocks

I am a newcomer to stock trading so please excuse the lack of technical knowledge. I primarily invest with Robinhood.

I bought some  Symantec  which recently got bought out by Broadcom. Since then the stock name has changed to Norton LifeLock and the stock prices are about the same. I read an older report from August that said that Symantec will pay a dividend of $12 per share in q4 of 2020.

Should I sell the Norton stock now in case it goes down again? How does it affect my dividend if I sell now?

Comment: Did you mean a dividend of $12 per share or 12 cents per share?  Regarding the dividend, [read this:](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/116454/what-is-an-advantage-of-getting-dividends-from-stock)

Comment: @BobBaerker It's a $12 per share special dividend to return the proceeds of a spin-off to shareholders.

Comment: @D Stanley - Thx, got it.  I now see that you clearly explained this in your answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your facts are a bit off. Symantec is not getting bought out - it is *selling* it's Enterprise Security business (and its name) to Broadcom and focusing on Norton products. The proceeds of that sale will be distributed to shareholders in a special dividend.

> How does it affect my dividend if I sell now?

You won't get it. But it shouldn't matter - the stock will drop by $12 when it pays the dividend, so you can either sell a $24 stock now or wait and have a ~$12 stock (if the price doesn't change) and $12 in cash. Between now and then, it's anybody's guess whether the stock will go up or down, but the dividend shouldn't factor into your decision.

Comment: The dividend might matter for tax purposes?